# Analogue of Schur indicator for reps in p-adic fields

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we have a finite group $G$, a division algebra $X$ over $\Bbb Q_p$ with (some) maximal subfield $L$ and an irrep $V$ of $G$ over $L$ (one may assume that everything is separable to make life easier). We can compute invariants $$\nu_s := \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_{V}(g^s).$$

Can we tell whether $V$ is induced from some $L' \subset L$, or admits an $X$-structure looking at those numbers?

P. S. I tried to prove easy part of Frobenius-Schur theorem (i. e. that those numbers can only be roots of unity or zero) but failed to do so; it's just false for $s \neq [L:\Bbb Q_p]$, if my computations are correct, but I may have failed at checking irreducibility. If it holds in case they are equal, or in general, I'd be happy to know why.

Comment: Just to check terminology:  $V$ is induced from $L'$ means $V = V' \otimes_{L'} L$ for some $G$-rep'n $V'$ over $L'$, and $V$ has an $X$-structure means that the $L$-action on $V$ extends to an $X$-action by $G$-morphisms of $V$? \\ Also, do you assume anything about $p$ and the order of $G$?

Comment: Yes for meaning of induced, by $X$-structure I just mean that $V$ is obtained from $X[G]$-module by restriction to $L[G] \subset X[G]$, probably it means same as you written. I do not want to assume that $G$ has no $p$-elements.

Comment: We mostly mean the same thing.  I just wanted to check that, in $X[G]$, $X$ commutes with $G$.

Comment: For $p>2$, there exist finite groups of exponent $p$ with characters of arbitrary large degree, for example extraspecial $p$-groups of exponent $p$. Then $\nu_p$ is just the character degree for these groups, and can be arbitrarily large. I doubt that these numbers tell you much about irreps over $p$-adic fields.

Comment: @FriederLadisch, are the representations you [mention](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372096/analogue-of-schur-indicator-for-reps-in-p-adic-fields#comment941586_372096) (or enough of them to make sure that $\nu_p$ is unbounded) realised over $p$-adic fields?

Comment: @LSpice: well, they can be realized over any field containing the $p$-th roots of unity, so over $\mathbb{Q}_p(\varepsilon_p)$. If $V$ is one of my representations, I can also view it as representation over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of dimension $(p-1) \operatorname{dim} V$, it is still irreducible then, but not absolutely irreducible.